# Reducing Stroke width to shape Drawable leaves spaces in all sides

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I am facing some unexpected issue with `drawable` 
I have four views having same `background drawable`. I have used `LinearLayout` with weight to manage them horizontally. 
Code below for `xml`

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_cell_palette"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/ll_options"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/color_1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_palette_tab"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/color_2"

                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_palette_tab"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/color_3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_palette_tab"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/color_4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_palette_tab"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="+"
                    android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                    android:textSize="20sp" />

            </LinearLayout>
```

and `bg_palette_tab.xml` is also below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="@dimen/size_01"
        android:color="@color/light_grey" />

</shape>
```

I am changing border width of selected **`TextView`**  via `GradientDrawable` 
as below:-

```
 if (selectedView.getBackground() instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            ((GradientDrawable) selectedView.getBackground()).setStroke(5, ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black));
        }
```

but only in first `TextView` left spaces along all the sides. I don't get whats going on. Please help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: tried `selectedView.invalidate()` ?

Comment: @pskink I have tried that but it is not working

Comment: then use a workaround like this: `GradientDrawable#setUseLvel(false)` - call it each time you are calling `setStroke`

Comment: Thanks it is working perfectly now.

Comment: there is a bug imho (other people can think its a feature though) so you need that workaround... - basicaly you need to call any method that sets `mGradientIsDirty` to `true`